# Does oRTP supports transmitting RTP over TCP?

Tags: tcp, rtp

I want know dose the oRTP lib supports transmitting RTP data over TCP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since RTP over TCP is defined in [RFC 4571](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4571) and this is not listed as a [supported feature](http://www.linphone.org/technical-corner/ortp/features) of the library the answer will probably be No.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answers. I have learned the source code of oRTP and found the function of "rtp_session_set_transports". I wonder if I can use this function to implement RTP over TCP. But I have no idea how to achieve that.

Comment: From a short look I would say that this function is not the place your are looking for. Again, I doubt that oRTP supports what you want.

Comment: I saw this before http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/linphone-developers/2012-02/msg00005.html

Comment: Actually, Nowadays I am implementing a Bi-directional audio program based on SIP. I use the libeXosip+mediastreamer2 libs to achieve that. But the problem is that I want transmit the SIP and RTP(audio data) over TCP. Now I know "IPPROTO_TCP" option can let the SIP over TCP. But I have no idea how to let the RTP transmit over TCP. Does the mediastreamer2/ortp lib support RTP over TCP? Do you have any suggestions about transmitting RTP over TCP?

Comment: Again, I doubt that oRTP supports TCP directly and I even doubt that it would be enough to write your own RtpTransport class do deal with it because it needs to be properly announced within the SDP too. But that's only from a short look - you better ask at oRTP mailing lists for more trustable inforamtion.